# The sum of the biggest member and smallest member equal to $11$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

In how many subsets of $A=\{1,2,3,..,10\}$ the sum of biggest and smallest member equal to $11$

> $a.320$
>
> $b.328$
>
> $c.341$
>
> $d.352$
>
> $e.364$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $1$ and $10$, then you can include any number from the rest of the numbers. So how many distinct subsets does the set $\{2,3,...,8,9\}$ has? Now similarly choose $2$ and $9$ and find all distinct subsets from $\{3,4,...,7,8\}$. And so on and so forth. At the end it should be an easy calculation.

Comment: Yes with your idea it should be:$2^8+2^6+2^4+2^2+2^0$?

Comment: but the set $\{2,9\}$ has also the needed specs

Comment: @TahaAkbari exactly.  And computing that number, is it on the list?  Yes?  Good.

Comment: @saturatedexpo Note that we include that subset when we choose the empty set from $\{3,4,5,6,7,8\}$

Comment: Yes it is right $341$.

Comment: @saturatedexpo the answer is indeed correct.  All cases of $2$ being smallest and $9$ being largest are taken care of in the term $2^6$.  Among the $2^6=64$ are things such as $\{2,9\},\{2,3,9\},\{2,4,5,8,9\},\dots$

Comment: @JMoravitz ah, ok, i just didn't understand your post fully

Answer (score 1):

Except for the set $\{5,6\}$, all subsets whose biggest and smallest numbers sum to $11$ come in pairs, namely those that include $5$ and those that don't.  Thus the number of such subsets is odd.  Since $341$ is the only odd number among the multiple choices offered, it must be the answer.